# readObject reads even after connection is closed

Tags: java, sockets

I've got a server and client apps. I use one connection to send objects using Socket class. Client does something like this:

```
while(true)
{
  //in is ObjectInputStream I get from Socket
  MyObject object=(MyObject)in.readObject();
  //do something and then wait for another object to handle
}
```

Everything works nice in local network, but now my server is on another machine. If I wait for half an hour and then stop server, client will continue to read object. This is my netstat -tnlpa

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      497/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      527/sendmail
tcp        0      0 82.146.53.193:22            188.162.39.104:54454        ESTABLISHED 26849/sshd
tcp        0      0 82.146.53.193:22            91.245.35.88:50231          ESTABLISHED 26114/sshd
tcp        0      0 82.146.53.193:22            91.245.35.82:50617          ESTABLISHED 26312/sshd
tcp        0      0 82.146.53.193:22            188.162.39.104:13128        ESTABLISHED 26768/sshd
tcp        0     84 82.146.53.193:22            188.162.39.104:51065        ESTABLISHED 26487/sshd
tcp        0      0 82.146.53.193:22            91.245.35.88:50229          ESTABLISHED 26107/sshd
tcp        0      0 82.146.53.193:22            91.245.35.89:52246          ESTABLISHED 26821/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      497/sshd
```

My server app port is 2407. As you can see there is no 2407, but my client app is still working. It is still waiting for an object. It will read forever. How can I fix it? I can not provide a code, because it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your try { } catch block for the readObject() call inside your while loop. If you place it outside of the while loop, the exception cause  execution to jump outside of the loop

Comment: This is how it was designed. If IOException is catched, my client should die.

Comment: @Tony That doesn't  address the issue in any way. Your question is about the fact that your client *doesn't* die: so where *is* the try/catch? And what does it catch? And what does it do then?

Comment: try/catch is outside the loop. If IOException is catched, my app closes connection and dies.

Answer (score 0):

It throws an `EOFException` when it reaches the end of the stream.

Of course if you *abort* the peer the pending read will never see end of stream. The solution to that is a read timeout on the socket.